# Sorting an array of objects by alphabetical order of a property of an object in php?

Tags: php, loops, object, alphabetical, usort

Here is an example of what I want, I basically want my retailers object to be sorted alphabetically by the name of of each retailer but I am not sure of the correct syntax on how to achieve it:

```
foreach($this->retailers as $retailer){
    $retailer->getName(); // Sort objects in $this->retailers by the alphabetical order of $retailer->getName().
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `usort` function:

```
usort($this->retailers, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->getName(), $b->getName());
});
```